# python 2.7 to 3.3 string encode/decode changes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am just fixing a 2.7 script to 3.5 and ran into some decode/encode issues.

```
 id = entry.attrib['{http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}id']
 code = id.split('-')[2]
 doc['code'] = (code + u"-area").decode('utf-8')
```

above is the 2.7 version that reads stuff from a xml file. What is the correct way of doing this in 3.3 since some encoding stuff was changed and 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' any more.

I have seen this also: `.encode('UTF-8').decode('utf-8')`  do this have any effect ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data - The initial document should be parsed correctly, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.X already holds unicode characters, so I think you do not need to use `.decode('utf-8')`. In the moment you need to store in someway/somewhere your `doc['code']` then you can use `.encode('utf-8')` and then retrieve it through `.decode('utf-8')`